# What dictates the datetime format of DB when ADO.Net runs query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have a simple test query run against a SQL Server database.

```
SELECT IsDate('1' + '/' + '25' + '/' + '1993')
```

When I run it against a database with

```
set dateformat dmy
```

It correctly returns 0

When I run it against a database with

```
set dateformat mdy
```

It correctly returns 1

Now the problem is when I'm running this query from a `SqlCommand` object in .Net I don't get the result I expect.

The rub is that I'm setting my thread's culture info and datetime format to d/m/y.  Even when my thread is running in a d/m/y format AND my database is set to d/m/y I still get 1 back from my query when run from `SqlCommand`.

**Sample code:** (note: `QuickQuery` is just a wrapper method which runs a `SqlCommand` against my selected database)

```
string query = $" SELECT IsDate('1' + '/' + '25' + '/' + '1993')";
var dt = QuickQuery(query);

return $"{dt.Rows[0][0]}" + $"            {new DateTime(1993, 1, 25)}";
```

The output of this = "1                  25/01/1993 00:00:00"

What is determining that the `SqlCommand` is running in a context of m/d/y when my actual database and current thread are set to d/m/y?

I have confirmed my database setting with

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

**Edit 1:**

Just a quick note - I appreciate the input about doing things a better way, that is valuable. For this particular case I don't get to pick the context of the problem sadly, I just get to fix it. I have a `varchar` column for each value month, day, and year. They can be null, or text. From that I have to create date time comparisons with actual `datetime` columns with the ability to work with any datetime format on the server and on the running thread!

Comment: Looking at the docs, it looks like `set dateformat` applies to the *current session*. Ideally, just make sure you don't rely on the date format at all - if you always use parameterized SQL instead and use `DateTime` values, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You should add a parameter to your query that uses a DataTime parameter rather than a String (VarChar).

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the docs information.  I was reading from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql and did not see any such comment!  Which official docs did you find so I can get up to speed on these details?

Comment: I followed the link at the bottom to [SET statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql) - "The Transact-SQL programming language provides several SET statements that change the current session handling of specific information. "

Comment: @JonSkeet Your comment is the correct answer for this case.  When I add the SET command to my SqlCommand I get the output I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially: avoid the problem completely. Never talk about dates as strings. Use parameters, which are well defined and typed.

Essentially (switching to [Dapper syntax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper), since it supports parameters):

```
 DateTime date = ...
 var dt = connection.QuerySingle<DateTime>("select @date + 2", new {date});
```

The same goes for other data - you get similar issues with numbers and decimal separators and group separators, and the way to get it right **is not** to learn the format that SQL Server wants: it is to *not use strings*, but to pass parameterized values. It'll also make it harder to accidentally fall into SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: I appreciate your advice and will try to use parameters when I can.  However, I'm working on a existing database with decently sized queries that have a lot of logic in them.  I can't change the database, but I have to try and support different formats.  I have to do this in the confines of the existing structure and design.

Comment: @AdamHeeg I didn't suggest changing the database at all - just the way you query it

Comment: I don't see why the queries being large make it infeasible to use parameterized SQL...

Comment: @JonSkeet if anything, it makes it *even more important*, because otherwise a: query plan cache saturation, and b: impossible to easily see errors due to code density

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll have to think more on it.  The data I'm using for the date is coming from separate columns for each day, month, year value (as noted in edited question).  So, they are not actually a parameter as my test case shows.  Doing all the logic in a query is new for me.